# Data in Oracle Database table is not being fully updated

Tags: c#, oracle

I want to update an Oracle Database table after querying the table and applying an encryption function to the retrieved data from some fields. However, my code (below) does not work correctly:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb))
            conn.Open();
            OracleCommand select = new OracleCommand("select  empno,FNAME,LNAME from employee", conn);
            OracleDataReader reader = select.ExecuteReader();
            Int64 vempno = 0;
            String fnameValue = "";
            String lnameValue = "";
            String afterConcatfname = "";
            String afterConcatlname = "";

           if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    vempno = reader.GetInt64(0);
                    fnameValue = reader.GetString(1);
                    lnameValue = reader.GetString(2);
                    REA rea = new REA();
                    afterConcatfname = rea.Encrypt(fnameValue, rea.GenerateKey());
                    afterConcatlname = rea.Encrypt(lnameValue, rea.GenerateKey());
                }

                reader.Close();
                }

            OracleCommand update = new OracleCommand("update employee set fname =:fname, lname =:lname where empno =:empno", conn);
            OracleParameter fname = new OracleParameter("fname", afterConcatfname);
            OracleParameter lname = new OracleParameter("lname", afterConcatlname);
            OracleParameter empno = new OracleParameter("empno", vempno);
            update.Parameters.Add(fname);
            update.Parameters.Add(lname);
            update.Parameters.Add(empno);
            update.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

I don't receive any error but the program encrypts only the last record with all the encrypted values. I want to encrypt every row.

Comment: Explaining what is the error received should be your first thing to do when you ask a question like this.

Comment: I'm guessing the update logic needs to be *inside* the loop, so that it executes once per row..

Comment: I'm guessing that the using statement block contains only the call to Open and nothing else. So no connection and a lot of errors.

Comment: I dident receive any error ,but the program encrypts only the last record by all the encrypted values , I want to encrypt row by row

Comment: Try posting an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it'll help you get answers faster.

Answer (score 0):

> "I dident receive any error ,but the program encrypts only the last record by all the encrypted values  "

That's the logic of your code. Basically, what you are doing is this:

```
loop
    read one row
    encrypt one row
end loop
update one row
```

> " I want to encrypt row by row  "

So you need to move the update logic into the loop, so that it is executed for each row.

A better solution would be to replace row-by-row processing with a set operation, but that's a different question.